# Responsive layout with background image in css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

so i have to code a responsive layout that is very very similar to this solar system picture i'm linking.

Basically i'm using as page background an image of just the sun and the planets' orbits and now i have to place all the planets as SVGs right on top of their own orbit's line, like in the picture.

Positioning the planets using position: absolute is easy but when i shrink the page everything becomes messy, of course.

The background image is already responsive but how can i make it so the planets as well stay in place even after i shrink/expand the page?

[image: solar system]

Comment: I suggest using [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and placing SVGs for each viewport size and maybe it is better to use relative units like % or vh or vw.

Comment: @FarshadVaghari currently i am trying putting them into a grid and yes i will be using a few media queries/breakpoints too (i am using tailwind) but i still feel like there's a faster and cleaner way to do all of this  thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a way: i used a grid that covers the entire page and put the SVGs of the planets in each grid's box. I'm using tailwind and helped myself with this website btw https://www.tailwind-tools.com/grid